# Spring cloud gateway route locator and discovery locator

Tags: spring-cloud-gateway

I have a spring-cloud gateway application with the activated discovery locator that creates routes based on services registered with a DiscoveryClient (Eureka):

```
spring:
  cloud:
    gateway:
      discovery:
        locator:
          enabled: true
          lowerCaseServiceId: true
          filters:
            - name: Retry
              args:
                retries: 10
```

In the Gateway Application itself, I define a route using RouteLocatorBuilder:

```
@Bean
    public RouteLocator routeLocator(RouteLocatorBuilder routeLocatorBuilder) {
        return routeLocatorBuilder.routes()
                .route(r -> r
                        .path("/test/**")
                        .filters(filters -> filters.addResponseHeader("testHeaderName", "testHeaderValue"))
                        .uri("lb://test-service"))
                .build();
    }
```

Based on that, I have the following questions:

1. When a request is sent via the gateway to the test-service, I observe that addResponseHeader filter is present in a filter chain. However, the Retry filter is missing. Is it possible to add filters from discovery.locater to the route defined by RouteLocatorBuilder? If this is the case, could you please hint on how to do it?
2. Considering that discovery.locator is enabled would it be possible to avoid explicitly providing a service id in the URI of a route? I.e. instead of ...uri(lb://test-service) specify ...uri(lb://serviceId) and make discovery locator resolve it automatically?

Thank you very much for time and consideration.